# BIOS Password Help Needed

Tags: bios, passwords

So I have an Acer Aspire E1-571. I'm trying to get into BIOS(you know when computer/laptops starts and you press F2 and an old fashion panel comes up). 
But the problem is that when I press the F2 button It asks for a password.
Buttt I never set a password for bios (don't even know how to do it)
I tried asking at Acer Community Forums but there responses are dull and not helping much. 
soooo... any help i guess?

Comment: [How to Reset an Acer BIOS Password](http://www.tech-faq.com/how-do-i-reset-an-acer-bios-password.html)

Answer (score 1):

Resetting that password usually requires one of the following:

- Remove BIOS battery (on motherboard inside laptop) for several minutes
- Short CMOS jumper on motherboard (Clear CMOS, Clear RTC)
- Remove laptop battery for several (12 or so) hours